# How to reach The CLR Type of an EntitySet in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to write a convention that sets the `SchemaName` automatically with some part of the entity namespace. Some code as follows:

```
class SchemaFromNameSpaceConvention : IConceptualModelConvention<EntitySet> 
{
    public void Apply(EntitySet item, DbModel model)
    {
        var ns = // some code to find namespace
                 // for example:  item.ElementType.NamespaceName;

        var match = Regex.Match(ns, @"MyCompany.(?<SchemaName>\w*).*");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            var schemaName = match.Groups["SchemaName"].Value;
            item.Schema = schemaName;
        }
    }
```

Consider following model and `DbContext`:

```
// In MyCompany.Accounting.Models.dll

namespace MyCompany.Accounting.Models
{
    public class Invoice
    {
        public int Number{ get; set; }
    }
}

// In DatabasePart.Contexts.dll
namespace DatabasePart.Contexts
{
    public AccountingDbContext : DbContext
    {
        // ...
        public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For namespace, I want to find `MyCompany.Accounting.Models` but `item.ElementType.NamespaceName` returns `DatabasePart.Contexts`.

**Question:** how do I reach the namespaces of the underlying type from an `EntitySet`?

Comment: `but item.ElementType.NamespaceName returns DatabasePart.Contexts.` that's the expected behavior. As if item is an instance of AccountingDbContext which holds the invoices. Can you try using `item.ElementType.GetCollectionType().NamespaceName`?

Comment: @JevgeniGeurtsen its value is something strange: `Transient`. The value of `item.ElementType.GetReferenceType().NamespaceName` is also `Transient`